# Sum with 2 different variables

Tags: plotting

I want to plot Contour or Streamplot a function with a sum. The first part (`Abs[v/u]>1`) looks like this:

$L(u,v)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{2s+1} (\frac{u}{v})^{2s} Q_{2s}(v)$

```
    l1[u_, v_] := l1[u, v] = 
        1 - Sum[((-1)^s/(2*s + 1))*(u/v)^(2*s)*q[v], {s, 0, Infinity}]
```

with q:(I named it in my code q[v])

$Q_{2s}=\sum_{p=0}^{2s}(-1)^p [J_p(v)J_{2s-p}(v)+J_{p+1}(v)J_{2s+1-p}(v)]$

```
q[v_] := q[v] = Sum[((-1)^p)[BesselJ[p, v]*BesselJ[2*s - p, v] + 
           BesselJ[p + 1, v]*BesselJ[2*s + 1 - p, v]], {p, 0, 2*s}]
```

My problem is, that I have a `s` and a `p` in my sum. How do I tell Mathematica how to perform this?
I tried substituting s and p with values, but it only gives me a blank plot.

I used this:

```
Plot[
  Table[
    l1[500, u, v], 
    {s, {1, 10, 100, 150, 50}}, 
    {p, {1, 10, 100, 150, 50}}
  ] // Evaluate, {u, 0, 10}
]
```

Is it wrong to use `Table`?
And in my actual plot I don't want to substitute `s and p`.

Comment: I have a few question: 1) why do you have `n` as an argument to `l1` but you never use it? 2) when you invoke `l1` in the `Table`, you use it as `l1[u, v, 500]`; from your definition, though, I thought that the `u, v` parameters would be in the second and third position instead. Is that possible a mistake?

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually dont have a `n` in`l1` . 2) It could be, I have to admit, that I wasnt quite sure what to put on which position. So I tried it out.

Comment: OK then could you check your code and edit your question to reflect the correct expressions? You can do so at any time by clicking on the "edit" link directly under the question. Sjoerd was also kind enough to reformat your code so it is more legible; take a look at [these guidelines](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1585/27951) to post better code here on MMA.SE.

Comment: You are also using `p` as a summation variable in the definition of `q`. Is that clash of variable names intended?

Comment: By the way, `Evaluate` is preferred to `Release` (and has been since 1991 :P ).

Comment: @PatrcikStevens yes, there is a p in that function and I don't know how to handle it yet^^

Comment: donut, apart from the variable conflicts, evaluating any one of your functions, even the simpler `q[v]` is extremely time-consuming. I can see no way that you can hope to plot these expressions as they are. It may be in your best interest if you could find any possible analytical simplifications. The brute force approach might not be indicated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an typo corrected, the expression for `q` is

```
q[v_, s_] := Sum[((-1)^p) (BesselJ[p, v]*BesselJ[2*s - p, v] + 
     BesselJ[p + 1, v]*BesselJ[2*s + 1 - p, v]), {p, 0, 2 s}]
```

It is instructive to plot it for various `s`

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[q[v, s], {s, 0, 10}]], {v, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All,
    AxesLabel -> {v, "q"}]
```

[image]

Evidently, `q` decreases rapidly as `s` is increased.  Therefore, it is practical to truncate the series in `l1`.  Additionally, it makes sense to combine the two sums and perform them numerically.

```
l1[u_, v_] := 1 - NSum[((-1)^s/(2*s + 1))*(u/v)^(2*s)*((-1)^p) 
    (BesselJ[p, v]*BesselJ[2*s - p, v] + BesselJ[p + 1, v]*BesselJ[2*s + 1 - p, v]), 
    {s, 0, 10}, {p, 0, 2 s}]
```

The requested `ContourPlot` is

```
ContourPlot[l1[u, v], {u, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 10}, FrameLabel -> {u, v}, ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image]